# How to have custom menu Item CSS Classes for wp_page_menu() or wp_list_pages()

Tags: menus, navigation, sub-menu, wp-list-pages

I want to add custom classes to my menu items. For every subpage I show its siblings as a navigation:

```
 global $post;     

        if ( is_page() && $post->post_parent ) {


            $args = array(
                'sort_column'  => 'menu_order',
                'title_li'     => '',
                'child_of'=> $post->post_parent
            );
            $childpages = wp_list_pages($args );

        }
```

This gives me a list with links. I want to give every anchor element the same custom class. How do I do that?

Comment: Is it intended for anchor CSS styling or other purposes?

Comment: Yes, it is for css styling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the ways is to extend `Walker_Page` class. See comment in the code to know where changes go.

```
class My_Siblings_CSS_Walker_Page extends Walker_Page {
    public function start_el( &$output, $page, $depth = 0, $args = array(), $current_page = 0 ) {
        if ( $depth ) {
            $indent = str_repeat( "\t", $depth );
        } else {
            $indent = '';
        }

        $css_class = array( 'page_item', 'page-item-' . $page->ID );

        if ( isset( $args['pages_with_children'][ $page->ID ] ) ) {
            $css_class[] = 'page_item_has_children';
        }

        if ( ! empty( $current_page ) ) {
            $_current_page = get_post( $current_page );
            if ( $_current_page && in_array( $page->ID, $_current_page->ancestors ) ) {
                $css_class[] = 'current_page_ancestor';
            }
            if ( $page->ID == $current_page ) {
                $css_class[] = 'current_page_item';
            } elseif ( $_current_page && $page->ID == $_current_page->post_parent ) {
                $css_class[] = 'current_page_parent';
            }
        } elseif ( $page->ID == get_option('page_for_posts') ) {
            $css_class[] = 'current_page_parent';
        }

        $css_classes = implode( ' ', apply_filters( 'page_css_class', $css_class, $page, $depth, $args, $current_page ) );

        if ( '' === $page->post_title ) {
            $page->post_title = sprintf( __( '#%d (no title)' ), $page->ID );
        }

        $args['link_before'] = empty( $args['link_before'] ) ? '' : $args['link_before'];
        $args['link_after'] = empty( $args['link_after'] ) ? '' : $args['link_after'];

        $output .= $indent . sprintf(
            // '<li class="%s"><a href="%s">%s%s%s</a>', // before
            '<li class="%s"><a href="%s" class="my-custom-css-class">%s%s%s</a>', // after 
            $css_classes,
            get_permalink( $page->ID ),
            $args['link_before'],
            apply_filters( 'the_title', $page->post_title, $page->ID ),
            $args['link_after']
        );

        if ( ! empty( $args['show_date'] ) ) {
            if ( 'modified' == $args['show_date'] ) {
                $time = $page->post_modified;
            } else {
                $time = $page->post_date;
            }

            $date_format = empty( $args['date_format'] ) ? '' : $args['date_format'];
            $output .= " " . mysql2date( $date_format, $time );
        }
    }
}
```

Use this custom Walker in your template:

```
$args = array(
    'sort_column' => 'menu_order',
    'title_li'    => '',
    'child_of'    => $post->post_parent
    'walker'      => new My_Siblings_CSS_Walker_Page() // use Walker here
);
// $childpages = wp_list_pages($args);
wp_list_pages($args); // as you utilize default 'echo' parameter (true)
```

The way much easier is to use jQuery.

Comment: I would advise strongly against this, as you are basically replacing a part of WordPress core with your own functionality. Even though you're extending the `Walker_Page` class, you're overwriting a significant chunk of native WordPress code. This results in **inconsistency** if the functionality of WordPress core is changed (which happens a lot). As @Mathias needs this for CSS styling, using a WordPress native filter to alter the behaviour of the parent element is much more secure and scalable solution.

Comment: @engelen This `walker` is used only when it's explicitly called. It *extends*, not *replaces*.  If `walker` parameter is undefined, all *list* functions use default Walkers, so none of the basic functionality was hurt. Also, this method is much more flexible and allow other magic tricks with lists.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of that. I should have been more specific in my first sentence: you're replacing WordPress' native functionality for this instance, but you're still replacing it. As WordPress is not set up very modular, you're copying tens of lines of code from the current version of WordPress and altering just a single one (for adding `my-custom-css-class`). Now, if WordPress is updated, all other page lists are changed according to the new `start_el` code, but it isn't for your custom Walker. Thus, you're potentially using outdated code.

Comment: There's a filter available to change WordPress' behaviour in this case, and it should be used. It's specifically intended for this purpose, and is future-proof. In practice, extending the walker will probably not need to problems, but it's bad practice **when a fitting filter is available**.

Comment: @engelen +1. I looked into `Walker_Page` `diff` between v.3.9.11 and v.4.4.2 and I agree with you on "*potentially using outdated code*". On the other hand, I never had any problems with extended Walkers.

Answer (score 3):

There is no good filter to add the CSS classes to the anchor (`<a>`) elements, but as you need it for CSS styling you can use the filter for the `<li>` elements. This filter is called [`page_css_class`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/page_css_class/), which is, natively, used solely in listing pages through `wp_list_pages()`. It filters the classes used for the `li`-tags.

To use this filter, simply hook into it:

```
function wpse222112_pagelist_item_css_classes( $classes ) {
    $classes[] = 'wpse222112-class';
    return $classes;
}

add_filter( 'page_css_class', 'wpse222112_pagelist_item_css_classes' );
```

If you need it only for this menu, be sure to remove it after calling `wp_list_pages()` using

```
remove_filter( 'page_css_class', 'wpse222112_pagelist_item_css_classes' );
```

For the sake of completeness: there is also a filter for the entire output of the page list, which you would need to use if it were necessary to add a class to the anchor tags (which it isn't in your case). This filter is [`wp_list_pages`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/wp_list_pages).